# Android: How to connect oracle database using Android Java code?

Tags: java, android, oracle, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

Few questions :

I am coding for android app, and have oracle account (database) and wondering if there are specific ways to connect from android to oracle database ?.

Or are there any easier ways to connect to database rather than oracle?.

Is there specific connecting strings I have to follow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to connect to an external database, you'll need a webservice that will do the job. The only database that Android makes direct access is the SQLite. For more information about saving data in your android device, you can reffer to this link: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html. If you go for the webservice, I would recommend you to check the Volley library: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html